# Should I delete leftover registry items after uninstalling programs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, uninstall, revo-uninstaller

Someone on another website recommended me to use [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/) to uninstall some stubborn program I couldn't manage to remove from my (win10) pc. I have removed program among some others but I have a question:

Should I delete "leftover registry items"? For every program I want to uninstall, it brings up [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlUWE.png).
It does let me create a registry backup every time so I think that's good?
Also, should I just delete the items in bold?

I'd be glad to know more about this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to keep the registry settings if you want to reinstall the program at a later time, if there are some user settings or preferences stored inside the registry (they might be stored elsewhere, though).

That said, the registry keys in the picture seem like they don't contain any user data, so they're probably not useful to you or your computer.

There is no "need" to delete these registry keys, and the amount of trash they leave behind is very small - however it does become significant with years of computer usage and countless programs installed/uninstalled.